# XML schema for UML 2.3 in XMI 2.1 file

Tags: uml, xmi

Where can I find a xml schema or a DTD for the following namespace: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901

Is there such a thing? I would like to export UML data model into a XMI file. In order to validate the exported XMI file I need this xml schema file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked for this in the past, and from what I understand, there is no XML schema for the XMI serialization of a UML model.

Instead, Section 6, "XML Document Production", of the MOF 2.0/XMI Mapping (see http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/) "specifies the XMI production of an XML document from a model based on the MOF 2.0 Core."  UML is an instance of MOF, so this also specifies the XMI serialization of a UML model.  Effectively, it specifies a grammar for XMI, then describes the use of the grammar to produce XMI for an instance of an model element.

It isn't a schema, but it's as close as I've found.

Answer (score 0):

The trick you can do is to create a java code from your database and then reverse your java code in order to get an UML 2.3 XMI 2.1 model. It works well and trying to convert a data model is not really possible because database is not an object model like UML.

I don't think that xml schema or DTD could do the job. What I do in order to validate my model is simply to open my model with the EclipseUML open source editor and then click on the model and use the model validation menu. Doing this validation manually is almost impossible because UML rules are not just about xml validation.